# Json Extractor | How to avoid initial few lines

Tags: jmeter, correlation

I have json path extractor and its response (given below), using match No.-1

`@..[?(@.unitName == 'Prod')].name`

My Json path giving the output as

Result[0]= Jon

Result[1]= Flip

Result[2]= Athar

Result[3]= Bobby

Result[4]= Azra

Result[5]= Colton

Result[6]= Sony

.

.

.

.

Result[1000]= Maik

I want to avoid first few lines randomly for each user .

Ex : For user 1 if first three lines are randomly ignored, the output should be as follows :

Result[0]= Bobby

Result[1]= Azra

Result[2]= Colton

Result[3]= Sony

.

.

.

.

Result[997]= Maik

I tried following expressions but it doesnt work

`@..[?(@.unitName == 'Prod')].name[$ {__Random (1,500)}]`

OR

`@..[?(@.unitName == 'Prod')].name[299]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try considering switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor), there you could do something like:

```
[?unitName=='Prod'].name | @[3:6]
```

[image]

More information:

- [JMESPath - Filters and Multiselect Lists](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-lists)
- [JMESPath - Slicing](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#slicing)
- [How to Performance Test Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-test-web-services)

Comment: This is a perfect solution and worked for me. Its really helped a lot . Thank You !